# control height of row within column R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a very simple question relating to R markdown, but have not been able to locate an answer on the web. In the below R markdown code is it possible to adjust the height of window 2 so that it is twice the height as window 3

Thanks

```
---
title: "Column Orientation"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Column
-------------------------------------
### Window1

Column
-------------------------------------
### Window 2

### Window 3
```